# NPM packages are invisible in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, npm

How do I reference javascript installed by NPM in my MVC Core 2.0 project?

Answer (score 0):

Npm javascripts we can't able to use alone in MVC application, we need to configure NPM and Gulp. Because node.js file handling npm so it required gulp check the [link i given for configuring it](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/283/asp-net-5-managing-client-side-dependencies-with-npm-bower-and-gulp)